# Get field value on change using Formik

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, formik

I'm using Formik library for React and Gatsby. I've got a `<Field />` component and I'm trying to get its current value using React Hook `useState` like this: `const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');`

The goal is to pass the first name value to another component (not the last name value) to create a personalized success message. For that I'm using `import { navigate } from 'gatsby';`

Here is the doc (navigate section): https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/

When I `console.log(firstName)` the state is updated but when I leave the field it is considered as empty which renders a configured error message `<ErrorMessage />` and prevents form submission. It is like the initial state has not been updated but on the contrary with `console.log` I can clearly see it was. I don't get it. Could someone explain this?

Below is a simplified version of my functional component code which includes Formik:

```
function ContactSection() {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');

return(
<Formik
    initialValues={{ firstName: '', lastName: '' }}
    validationSchema={yup.object({
        firstName: yup.string()
            .trim()
            .max(24, 'Must be 24 characters or less')
            .matches(/^[A-Za-z\s\-'éèàùç]+$/, 'First name is not valid')
            .required('Please enter your first name'),
        lastName: yup.string()
            .trim()
            .max(24, 'Must be 24 characters or less')
            .matches(/^[A-Za-z\s\-'éèàùç]+$/, 'Last name is not valid')
            .required('Please enter your last name'),
    })}
        onSubmit={(data, { resetForm }, e) => {
                    fetch("/", {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
                        body: encode({
                            "form-name": "contact",
                            ...data,
                        })
                    })
                        .then(() => {
                            resetForm();
                            // ??? How to pass firstName state (current input value) to Gatsby navigate function ???
                            navigate('/success/', { state: { firstName } });
                        })

                    e.preventDefault();
                }}
>
    {({ isSubmitting }) => (

                    <Form
                        name="contact"
                        method="post"
                        data-netlify="true"
                        data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field">

                        <Field type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact"></Field>
                        <Field type="hidden" name="bot-field" value="contact"></Field>

                        <div className={contactStyles.rowControl}>
                            <div className={contactStyles.fControl}>
                                <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name*</label>
                                <Field type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)} value={firstName}/>
                                <ErrorMessage
                                    name="firstName"
                                    render={msg => <span className={contactStyles.eMsg}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExclamationCircle} />{msg}</span>}
                                />
                            </div>

                            <div className={contactStyles.fControl}>
                                <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name*</label>
                                <Field type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" autoComplete="off" />
                                <ErrorMessage
                                    name="lastName"
                                    render={msg => <span className={contactStyles.eMsg}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExclamationCircle} />{msg}</span>}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className={contactStyles.bWrap}>
                            <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane} />SEND</button>
                        </div>

                    </Form>

                )}

            </Formik>
)}
```

Comment: remove change handler, use formik's `values.firstName`

Comment: @xadm Thank you for your answer but I don't really understand. I removed ```onChange``` but how to update the state without it and ```setFirstName```? I don't know where to use ```values.firstName```.

Comment: const [values] = useFormik() or prop from <Formik> component - check docs ... show more context - how/where you want to use it

Comment: @xadm I just edited my question to give more about the context. I hope I'm clear enough. I read the doc but there are still some elements I'm confused about. I'm still in a learning process.

Comment: `{({ isSubmitting, values }) => ( <> <SomeComponent data={values.firstName} />  <Form ... </> )}`

Comment: @xadm I think I wasn't clear enough with what I'm trying to achieve so I reedited my question. Sorry about that. The answer you gave me lead me to nowhere unfortunately. Consider me as a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for something like this:

```
  function ContactSection() {

    const { values, handleSubmit } = useFormik({ .... );
    
    onSubmit={(data, { resetForm }, e) => {
      ...
      ...
      navigate('/success/', { state: { firstName: values.firstName } });
```

BTW - Instead of redirect you can just render conditionally some `<Success firstName={values.firstName} />` inside this component (instead of `<Form/>`) using state-values from formik like `isSubmitting` (some `<Processing/>`), `status`/`setStatus` or own state (flag).